# problem of combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

A teacher needs to choose $11$ students from a class to participate in a contest. If he can make his choice of $12376$ possible ways, How many students can be chosen?
The formula I used: $C={n!\over m!(n-m)!}$ where $C=12376$, and $m=11$, so I need to find $n$(the number of students that are in the class) but i don´t know how to find $n$; by the way the answer is $17$ students, but I found this number by typing numbers in my calculator; I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Typing numbers in a calculator is a good approach. As a preliminary step, you might find an $n$ such that $\binom{n}{11}$ is "too big."

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine.  You might try $n=30$ in your calculator, find it is way too large, and use bisection.  You will get there quickly.  For $n,m$ enormous you can use Stirling's approximation $n!\approx \frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$ and the square root doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is "factorise" the value of $12376=2^{3}\cdot 7\cdot 13\cdot 17$. Now, $17$ and $13$ are elements in the consecutive sequence $<n-5, n-4, n-3, n-2, n-1, n>$. The question is whether the largest number is $17$ or $18$. However, we don't have any factors of $3$. What does this mean?